# Firebase .info/connected make false programatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am using  .info/connected for presence system in my chat app, I want disconnect .info/connected once user logout from app so he will not see online anymore.
(As after logout app will go to login page i.e app still in foreground and .info/connected is returning true)

Presence system working perfectly when app close,but I want to change status to offline once user logout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically control the connection state of the app yourself, you can call [`goOffline`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#go-offline) and [`goOnline`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#go-online) from your code. Going offline will close the connection that the client keeps to the Firebase backend, which in turns will make `.info/connected` become `false`.